# How to call functions through an index selection

Tags: python, list, function, indexing

I would like to know if it is possible to store and then call a function like you recall an indexed item from a list?

In the code below, `x` represents an index number I have yet to determine as the final function in this program. At some point later, I will add the code to print the list with their indexed function, but for now I would like to get this program to work. Index 0 is labeled blank because entering a zero can be confusing for some users.

The relevant code I am talking about:

```
print("Weights and Measurements will convert the Imperial measurments, into the corresponding metric measurement.")

programSelect = eval(input("Please choose a program from the list below, with its corresponding index number (1-x):" ))
programs = ["blank", "def tempConvert", "def distance"]
```

The idea is for the user to select a function by its index number. What I have no clue on doing is how to activate the individual functions like def tempConvert, or def distance and have their corresponding menus appear.

Think of it like this.

command prompt would read

> > > "Weights and Measurements will convert the Imperial measurments, into the corresponding metric measurement."
> > >
> > > "Please choose a program from the list below, with its corresponding index number (1-x):"

Say I enter 1 to select the def tempConvert function

It then should show me the following from the def tempConvert function

"Please use either Celsius or Fahrenheit"
"Please enter a temperature for Celsius: "
"Please enter a temperature for Fahrenheit: "

I know that I need to work on the individual programs, as to prevent the user from inserting a temperature in both Celsius and Fahrenheit. For now, the program works on its own, but I want it to work within a larger program.

Comment: Please get rid of `eval`: [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Comment: This typically refers to the term "callback". You set a variable to a function and call the function later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is easily done:

```
def function1():
    print "hi, I'm function1"
def function2():
    print "hi, I'm function2"
list_of_functions = [function1, function2]
....
list_of_functions[x]() # this calls the function at index x
```

Note that the functions are called `function1`, not `"def function1"`; every function is an object in python, and can be stored in a list, a dictionary or a variable just as you can store integers, strings or your own class instances.

Comment: Thank you for the code, it works well for starting the program, but fails to allow me to select the appropate function. It runs through each function of the list, without any control by the user.

Further once I run out of functions to activate, the program crashes. The problem is likely on my end, and so I begin the great journey to debug the code. Thanks again.